# MATLAB saved figures have scratches

Tags: matlab

I have a problem saving figures through MATLAB. Namely, when 'save as' option the saved figures have 'scratched' white areas. Example below

Screen capture of the actual figure:

[image]

Same figure saved as png through MATLAB

[image]

Has anybody encountered this problem? Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: Which Matlab version are you using?

Comment: The version I'm using is R2012a

Comment: How are you saving it?  Using the GUI menu "export" item?  Using the `print` command?  Using `getframe` ?

Comment: For the one in the post used "Save as..." in the GUI menu. Just now tried "export", with the same result. Tried 'print' command - still scratchy...

Comment: Have you tried saving it in a different format? Eps and TIFF generally works out great. For some reason it looks like only some values are getting scratched. I want to say it's a saturated pixel, but I am not sure if that's the case. Can you check the values around that point where it's scratching?

Comment: Tried the formats you suggested, still "scratchy". Scratching in the right hand side figure occurs in areas where the magnitude varies massively in a small area (between values of order 10^4 and 10^5). BUT if MATLAB figure is fine plotting them, why does it all go wrong when it saves the figure. ALSO this "scratching" is not isolated to this one case, it occurs for figures where the structure less developed, magnitude of values moderate. Also, I tried plotting and saving a single figure (rather than subplots), the "scratching" is tamer, but still there.

Comment: Looks like an overflow problem, like you had too large values in the colormap, especially the blue channel. Now idea why this would happen though. Can you post a minimal runnable example so we can try to reproduce the problem?